# Installing Wordpress on 14.04 - Apache2 Ubuntu Default Page appearing

Tags: apache2, wordpress

I went through the Wordpress installation process and I'm getting the Apache2 Ubuntu Default Page when I go to my ip. What did I do wrong?

Wordpress is installed in `/var/www/html`. My URL is `dancer.ly` and my IP is 127.0.0.1. Thanks!

Comment: To Give a clear answer, Please add these details: Path where Wordpress was installed, URL you accessed.

Comment: It's installed in /var/www/html. My URL is dancer.ly and my IP is 127.0.0.1. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You are most likely installing WordPress under the wrong path. You have the following options:

**Move the files**: Copy all the WordPress files from where ever you installed it to `/var/www/html`.

**Change the path used by apache**: change the `DocumentRoot` in the file `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf` to the path where you installed WordPress.

**Create a new vHost**: Create a new vHost, by adding another site. Copy the `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf` to something like `/etc/apache2/sites-available/wordpress.conf` and edit it to make your changes. You can than either use a `ServerName`, to access the server through an URL (for example by adding it to your `/etc/hosts` file), or disable the default host with `a2dissite 000-default`. Than you need to enable your new site with `a2ensite wordpress` (Change wordpress to whatever you named the conf file).

When you change the path or create a new vHost you need to restart apache: `/etc/init.d/apache2 restart`.

Maybe you also left the index.html in the directory `/var/www/html` when installing WordPress. Apache searches for the `index.html` before it searches for the `index.php`. So you should simply delete it

Comment: Hmm, I made sure that the Wordpress files are installed under /var/www/html/. In Libre Office, I can only open 000-default.conf as a read-only and it won't save in any other text edit program. Should I try the "Create a new vHost"? Thanks!

Comment: @Emily and what about the index.html?

Comment: Deleted. I only have index.php in the foldwer

Comment: Now my local IP (127.0.0.1) is showing "Error establishing a database connection" and my other one (192.168.1.114) is still showing the Apache default page. My domain (dancer.ly) is showing "This webpage is not available".

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same problem as the OP. What solved it for me was clearing my browser's cache actually. I even deleted the `index.html` file from any directory including and under `/var/www/html`, and it still showed up in my browser when I navigated to my server's IP.

Comment: Oh I didn't know about that function. Either way, I wasn't posing a question of my own- I was offering a solution to the OP's problem.

Answer (score 0):

That is due to multiple index files, like `index.html` and `index.php`.
All you need to do is to delete the `index.html` page in the /var/www/html folder, clear cache and reload the page, it should fix the issue.

Comment: Is that due to multiple index files, like index.html and index.php et cetera? Adding this to the answer would make it from ok(if it works) to good.

Comment: Yes, you are right it is because of that. Adding it. Thanks